# What hardware do I need if I need to frequently adjust the height and rotation of 2 Thunderbolt monitors?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I have a small apartment and have one Thunderbolt display, a retina MacBook Pro, and am considering a second Thunderbolt Display.

I plan on purchasing VESA kits for each display, but am getting hung up on what kind of hardware to buy to handle the rotation of screens and what I should do with my MacBook, and still make the small space aesthetically pleasing.

What options are there to rotate a monitor 90 degrees (so I can view long documents) and to rotate it back so I can multitask or watch videos?

What should I look for in a desk that would work well with this setup?

Comment: Your question seemed likely to be closed as off topic because it appeared to be a "shopping" question. I retargeted the question to (hopefully) be less likely to be closed. If you disagree with this, feel free to revert or further change my edit.

Comment: For what it's worth I went with this C-clamp monitor stand:  http://store.apple.com/us/product/H6017LL/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two 27" displays will (obviously) take up quite a bit of room. You'll probably want to look for a desk that has built-in mounting points for your VESA arms (or built-in VESA arms) so you don't have to hang the displays off the wall. (If you want to rotate the monitor, Apple's Thunderbolt displays don't have any built-in rotation ability, so you'll need an arm that does that, too. OS X's Displays preferences are where you'll go to set the rotation on the display.)

There are several different caddies for your MacBook (such as the [Henge Docks](http://www.hengedocks.com/index.html)) that will keep it out of the way of your displays.